# Event handling/Capturing

Tags: javascript, click, dom-events

I want to attach an event listener purely in Javascript to "ul" html tag so that when I clicked on any "li" an alert will display the value of that corresponding "li":

```
<ul>
    <li>A<li/>
    <li>B<li/>
    <li>C<li/>
</ul>
```

If a clicked on A it should alert A , same for B and C

Comment: You can read this https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_addeventlistener.asp

Comment: Did you try anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get all `li nodes` and add `click events` on each `nodes`
.

```js
var lis =  document.getElementById("div").getElementsByTagName("li")
for(var i=0;i<lis.length;i++){
 lis[i].addEventListener('click', function(e){
      alert(e.target.textContent);
   })

}

// As if you want to have single click event on ul itself

document.getElementById("ul").addEventListener('click', function(e){
      alert(e.target.textContent);
   })
```

```css
ul li {
  background: #cce5ff;
  margin: 5px;
  cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<div id="div">
<ul >
  <li>A</li>
  <li>B</li>
  <li>C</li>
</ul>
</div>

 <p> As if you want to have single click event on ul itself</p>
<hr>

<ul id="ul">
  <li>X</li>
  <li>Y</li>
  <li>Z</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var list = document.querySelector("#list");
list.addEventListener("click", function(ev) {
  if (ev.target !== list) console.log(ev.target.textContent);
  // console is easier to test than alert(ev.target.textContent);
});
```

```html
<ul id="list">
  <li>A</li>
  <li>B</li>
  <li>C</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I want it in pure JS and with single event listner on ul

Comment: @Crochers There is now only 1 listener. Also it was already was pure JS

Answer (score 0):

You can select ul by `getElementById` and bind it to the event `onclick`. Check the 
[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rafee/8t452qnu/)

Answer (score -1):

```js
document.querySelectorAll('li')
  .forEach(item =>
    item.addEventListener('click',
      () => alert('Item clicked')
    )
  );
```

```css
li {
  cursor: pointer;
}

li:hover {
  background: lightgrey;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 2</li>
</ul>
```

You have to loop through all `<li/>` elements inside the list and attach an [eventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) to them.

See code example to find out how it works.

Comment: That fiddle is empty